# WordPress home page loading popup dialog SyntaxError: Unexpected Token :

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I could not find anything online that matches my issue. When I load my homepage by typing it into the address bar, it loads fine. When I navigate to the homepage from another page on the site (by clicking the homepage link or the browser's back button), however, the following dialog box pops up.

"SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

When I click OK, the dialog box disappears and the homepage loads as usual. I want to know the source of this dialog box popup and get rid of it. Any ideas or advice for troubleshooting is appreciated.

I am using WordPress 4.0, Jquery 1.11.1, and Salient theme. The issue is reproducible on Chrome and Safari browsers. Again, typing the homepage url into the address bar and pressing enter does not cause the dialog box to pop up. Navigating to a totally different site and pressing Back also does not cause the popup.

Thank you!

Comment: this question is too vague.  can you at least add a link to the site having the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message comes from /wp-content/themes/salient/js/ajaxify.js

```
function _addtext(t) {
    try {
        $.globalEval(t);
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

The string value of t is

```
{ "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "WebSite", "url": "http://128.199.247.11/", "potentialAction": { "@type": "SearchAction", "target": "http://128.199.247.11/?s={search_term}", "query-input": "required name=search_term" } }
```

Reproducing the result:

```js
var t = '{ "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "WebSite", "url": "http://128.199.247.11/", "potentialAction": { "@type": "SearchAction", "target": "http://128.199.247.11/?s={search_term}", "query-input": "required name=search_term" } }';

try {
   $.globalEval(t);
} catch (e) {
   alert(e);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

It happens because this string is equivalent of the

```
<script>
{"@context": "...", and so on }
</script>
```

and js does not know what to do with it while trying to eval the code.

Comment: Hey @Cheery, thanks for your thorough explanation! Accordingly, it looks like whatever is calling the function _addtext is not passing it the complete string of code to run globalEval on. How do you recommend I find the source of the trouble?

Comment: @FullStackDev Disable or update 'Yoast WordPress SEO plugin'

Comment: Disabling it prevents the problem. @Cheery, you are AWESOME